# tcolorbox poster: draw a fit node in the background

Tags: tcolorbox

I'm trying to draw a fit node in the background using the poster library of tcolorbox. Unfortunately it does not work as expected, because the drawing is above. I tried to play with layers, but it does not work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[many,poster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    height=5cm,
    spacing=10mm,
    columns=3,
    rows=3,
  },
  coverage={
    overlay={
      % This does not work because there is a strange
      % shift...
      % \node[fit=(TCBPOSTER@A)(TCBPOSTER@B),inner sep=3mm,draw=red,fill=red!50!white,opacity=.7] {};
    }
  }
  ]
  \posterbox{name=A,column=2,row=1}{$A$}
  \posterbox{name=B,column=2,row=2}{$B$}
  \posterbox{name=C,column=3,row=2}{$C$}
  \draw [->] (TCBPOSTER@A) -- (TCBPOSTER@B);
  \draw [->] (TCBPOSTER@C) -- (TCBPOSTER@B);
  \node[fit=(TCBPOSTER@A)(TCBPOSTER@B),inner sep=3mm,draw=red,fill=red!50!white,opacity=.7] {};
  % Bonus if you can make this arrow appear completely without
  % manually tweaking coverage/right=2cm.
  \draw[->] (TCBPOSTER@C.east) -- ++(2cm,0cm);
\end{tcbposter}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering the main question is easy: add the fit node on the background layer.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[many,poster]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcbposter}[
  poster = {
    height=5cm,
    spacing=10mm,
    columns=3,
    rows=3,
  },
  coverage={
    overlay={
      % This does not work because there is a strange
      % shift...
      %\node[fit=(TCBPOSTER@A)(TCBPOSTER@B),inner sep=3mm,draw=red,fill=red!50!white,opacity=.7] {};
    }
  }
  ]
  \posterbox{name=A,column=2,row=1}{$A$}
  \posterbox{name=B,column=2,row=2}{$B$}
  \posterbox{name=C,column=3,row=2}{$C$}
  \draw [->] (TCBPOSTER@A) -- (TCBPOSTER@B);
  \draw [->] (TCBPOSTER@C) -- (TCBPOSTER@B);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
   \node[fit=(TCBPOSTER@A)(TCBPOSTER@B),inner
  sep=3mm,draw=red,fill=red!50!white,opacity=.7] {};
  \end{scope}
  % Bonus if you can make this arrow appear completely without
  % manually tweaking coverage/right=2cm.
  \draw[->] (TCBPOSTER@C.east) -- ++(2cm,0cm);
\end{tcbposter}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

I do not understand the bonus question. How should the arrow fit if you keep the size the same?

Comment: Oh, I'm so stupid, I was trying to use the layers without the scope environment, thinking that it would also work... Thanks a lot, sorry for the stupid question. For the bonus, I mean in standalone environment the border "cut" the arrow (while usually in tikz drawing the page fits to the whole drawing). I know it's possible to manually change the size using `coverage={right=2cm}`, but I'd like to avoid this manual tricks.

Comment: @tobiasBora I am not a `tcolorbox` expert but as far as I understand usually, unlike `tikzpicture`s, `tcolorbox` does not dynamically adjust the bounding box. In this case, if it did, how would that work? Should only the third column get wider? Probably not, this does not look good. Should all column widths grow? Possibly, but then you lose the nice feature of being able to produce a box of a fixed size. However, I cannot exclude that there are keys for that.

Comment: Oh, I would not touch the width of the borders (it would change the drawing otherwise), just the bounding box of the whole drawing to make sure all the external elements are drawn, like in tikz. But nevermind, it's another question, thanks!